# Blank country/state drop-down & sell to specific countries area in woocommerce setup

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am not able to select a country/state from the dropdown as it is blank and sell to specific countries area is blank as well. please help out!. [here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0rDT.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone help me to resolve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with your woocommerce installation. Please uninstall and start all over again and check.